# NewDocSet and JSLink

Tags: 2013, document-set, jslink, custom-field-types

I'm creating a custom field type and use JSLink for rendering this field in forms.
Unfortunately, when I try to create a new Document Set, my `.js` file is not attached to the page and field rendering does not work.

How to make JSLink work for `NewDocSet.aspx` page? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `NewDocSet.aspx` page is application page in `_layouts` folder, you can’t custom through UI/designer. So you cannot use JSLink to render the `NewDocSet.aspx`.

As a workaround, you should go to the folder which is located at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` in SharePoint server and make a copy of the `NewDocSet.aspx` page, then add JavaScript into the page to render the form.

Comment: Or work your script into the MasterPage and trigger it on the NewDocSet page, that way you won't have to go into the Layouts folder (which is not even possible in SharePoint Online)